# difference between entries in tnsnames.ora and DSN

Tags: windows, oracle, database-administration

We add server URL, port, etc while adding DSN as well as in tnsnames.ora then how adding an entry in tnsnames.ora is different from adding DSN(data source name) in ODBC?

Comment: Why have you tagged [tag:sql-server]?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about odbc, and you originally also tagged for sql-server, I'm going to assume that you are trying to connect from oracle to mssql via an oracle db link and gateway for odbc.

The tnsnames.ora and the odbc dsn come at two very distinct and different places in the "chain of events" of the connection.  When an oracle client (in the case of an oracle db link, the database itself *is* the requesting client) makes a connection request, the very first thing TNS has to do is resolve the server name or ip address, port, and service name of the target database.  This resolution is most often done by consulting the tnsnames.ora file of the requesting client process.

TNS then packages the request as a standard tcp package and hands it over to the OS network stack for delivery to the specified server and port.  Hopefully, there will be an oracle listener at that server and port, and said listener will know of the requested SID or service.  Notice that ODBC has not yet become involved.

Once the request arrives at the listener, the listener will interpret it and make a call to the necessary service handler.  In the case of a request to a non-oracle database, this service handler will be the Oracle Transparent Gateway.  It is here, in the configuration of the gateway, that a reference is made to the ODBC DSN, and the request passed off to the ODBC handler.

Most of the links in the chain are actually one alias, pointing to the next alias.  Therefore one (say the tnsnames.ora entry) does not have to be exactly the same as the next (odbc dsn) as long as the configuration points along the way make the correct translation.

Use of the odbc handler (and the dsn configuration) is not limited to Oracle, and is actually completely separate.  The same odbc dsn could be used by the oracle gateway, and by Excel, and by any other odbc capable application.

You can read more, and get some good graphic, in an article I wrote at https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/the-oracle-transparent-gateway/